# Unable to run Jbilling plugin as a jar

Tags: jbilling

I have create Payment plugin in Jbilling. If I use it in Jbilling source itself, it is working fine.
But if I create jar of plugin and put that jar into lib folder and made it's entry in BuildConfig.groovy as runtime 'jar name'.

when I compile source, it download the jar in grails folder, but when i am trying to add it in configuration/plugin, it is giving exception "ClassNotFound Exception".
How can i add plugin as a jar?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want to be included as a source to jBilling, simply copy the source or lib files into the lib directory. The `lib` directory in jB acts similar to the `ext` directory in java.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution. I modified run-app.bat, in that replace run-app to run-war and because of this all jars which are in lib folder, they automatically copied in war file and during runtime while I am trying to add as a plugin these jars also available and doesn't getting ClassNotFound Exception.